# How to setup a cron job for my scrapy crawlers using python-crontab or crontab -e

Tags: python, scrapy, cron

I am totally new to the cron jobs. Want to setup cronjobs.

Approach I used are not working

`crontab -e`

```
2 * * * * /home/user/Desktop/folder/scrapy crawl xyz
```

I want to see if its working every 2 minutes but didn't get any output.

I just want a simple step by step process to setup cronjobs.

Comment: You may want to go to "debugging crontab" in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add PATH to your cron:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

or `#!/usr/bin/python` to top of script

Comment: I add this to my python crawler?

Comment: path to crontab and `#!/usr/bin/python` to your crawler

Comment: is this correct after doing what you asked 2 * * * * /home/user/Desktop/folder/scrapy crawl xyz

Comment: Using `#!/usr/bin/python` is not recommended https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/#scl-script

Answer (score 1):

Make your script runnable.

```
chmod +x /home/user/Desktop/folder/scrapy
```

And add :

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ python
```

to your script.

Your crontab is correct and cron will run the script with the given parameters every 2 minutes.

Comment: I did that but its not running

Comment: Then your script does not have the shebang.

Comment: suppose the program prints something how to get the output?

Comment: It should be in the logs. Also, you can configure cron to send an email when a job is completed. That email will contain `stdout`.